# Python using dash and plotly to check ho to get input using dcc and having error

Tags: python, server, plotly, plotly-dash, wsgi

WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.

here is code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_table

app = Dash(__name__)

ALLOWED_TYPES = (
   "text", "number", "password", "email", "search",
   "tel", "url", "range", "hidden",
    )


 app.layout = html.Div(
[
    dcc.Input(
        id="input_{}".format(_),
        type=_,
        placeholder="input type {}".format(_),
    )
    for _ in ALLOWED_TYPES
]
+ [html.Div(id="out-all-types")]
 )


 @app.callback(
Output("out-all-types", "children"),
[Input("input_{}".format(_), "value") for _ in ALLOWED_TYPES],
  )
def cb_render(*vals):
return " | ".join((str(val) for val in vals if val))


 if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run_server(port=8051)
```

i try to give input dash but i have error look in this screenshot:[image]

Comment: What's the error? What you've shared so far are the standard messages when starting up a local dev server.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. According [to this plotly forum post](https://community.plotly.com/t/production-and-development-enviroments/21348/2), using a plotly dash app in a development server is fine if you're creating your plotly dash app for yourself, but has not been tested for security or performance in a production environment